# How to use AND/OR Building Block content in a Word 2007 template

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, microsoft-office-2007

I am creating a Schedule of Work template and am successfully using Developer Tab and Quick Parts to allow user to choose content on an "either/or" basis: either A; OR B; OR C; etc., essentially choose one option from many. One Building Block control, one paragraph, nice and clean.

Now what I need to do but cannot seem to figure out, is how to allow user to choose content on an "and/or" basis: either A AND B; A OR B AND C; B AND D AND E OR F; etc., essentially choose several options from many on a variable basis. One Building Block control, maybe one paragraph, maybe three or more paragraphs. Not so clean. I thought of building choice options for all possible paragraph combinations, but I can have as many as 7 or 8 different paragraphs, and that solution quickly becomes unworkable. Multiple controls--some of which will be left unused doesn't work either, since I cannot find an easy way to have a "Choose or Delete" control that actually deletes if  "Delete" is chosen.

Recommendations are most welcome.

Comment: Any chance you could provide a screenshot or a sample document that helps demonstrate your problem?